# Eclipse/Maven: "Unable to provision"

Tags: eclipse, maven

Having just upgraded to Eclipse Mars I am getting a number of errors on each POM file.

```
Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
  at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
```

All was working fine in my previous Eclipse installation. I have tried updating and cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I updated the java and all worked fine.